# Change value on a dropdown on the basis of a value selected in another dropdown in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning React and am creating a form that has two dropdowns. What I want is that, on selecting a particular value in the first dropdown, the second dropdown should automatically select a particular value.

For example, if I choose A in dropdown 1, then dropdown 2 should select B by default. 
I've seen other examples but these change all the values of the second dropdown and I don't want that. I just want a default value to be selected.

This is my code for the dropdowns -

```
   <select
      name="First"
      className="inputField dropdownForm "
      value={this.state.First}
      onChange={this.handleChange}
    >
      <option value="">Choose first alphabet</option>
      <option value="A">A</option>
      <option value="C">C</option>
    </select>


    <select
      name="SecondAlpha"
      className="inputField dropdownForm"
      value={this.state.secondAlpha}
      onChange={this.handleChange}
    >
      <option value="">Choose second alphabet</option>
      <option value="B">B</option>
      <option value="D">D</option>
    </select>
```

What changes and additions should I make?

Comment: Thats so simple, you can just set the secondAlpha state based on change of first select i.e. in handleChange just check the value and based on the value set your secondAlpha state.

Comment: can you update your question with attempted effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to add a condition in `handleChange` of the "first" dropdown:

```
handleChangeOfFirst = (e) => {
  if (e.target.value === "A") {
    this.setState({ secondAlpha: "B" });
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and help! I cannot believe I didn't think of this earlier and jumped straight to the complicated stuff!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid any condition may be this can help.

```
const obj = {A: 'B', C: 'D'};
handleChangeOfFirst = (e) => {
  this.setState({ secondAlpha: obj[e.target.value] });
};
```